# Java 8 way to loop using com.google.common.collect.Iterables.partition?

Tags: java, java-8, guava

Seems like this should be simple using `Stream.of` in some fashion, and yet....  :)

Here is the code I would like improve (`myEntryIds` is list of `Long` several thousand items in length):

```
List<MyEntityType> results = new ArrayList<>();

// batch up into groups of 1000 
for (final List<Long> partitionedEntryIds : 
       com.google.common.collect.Iterables.partition(myEntryIds, 1000)) {
        results.addAll(BeanConverter.convertList(
             myJpaRepository.findAll(partitionedEntryIds)));
}

return results;
```

Comment: This code looks simple and readable to me (except for the fully quelified class name). Why do you want to change it?

Comment: The FQCN was only for readability!  While I don't have a comprehensive list of reasons, I dislike the mutability of "results".  Not sure if this could be a candidate for parallelism, but definitely not in its current state.

Comment: It can't be parallel: you want all the queries to be made in the same transaction, the transaction is bound to the thread, and entities are not thread-safe. collect(toList()) also uses and returns a mutable ArrayList. Sothere wouldn't be any difference in that regard.

Comment: I did say "Not sure", I wanted to investigate the query itself returning a stream (Spring Data JPA can do that), but such parallelism isn't part of my question anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no `Iterables#partition` equivalent in JDK streams, but you could use `Streams#stream` helper and `toImmutableList()` collector from Guava (plus some method references which I personally like) to achieve your other goals:

```
final List<MyEntityType> myEntityTypes = Streams.stream(
    Iterables.partition(myEntryIds, 1000))
    .map(myJpaRepository::findAll)
    .map(BeanConverter::convertList)
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .collect(toImmutableList());
```

Comment: Very nice!  Thanks!